# Media queries interaction

Tags: media-queries

I have question about some CSS stuff. I'm currently using Boostrap to develop a web application. I have come in the situation where I have to set some media queries in my custom css which i use for styling and graphic. My question is will there be any conflict with those one in Boostrap CSS.

Comment: we answer code questions here on SO.  Share your code that is or isn't working along with the desired result you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Bootstrap, the best practice is to add your custom CSS code (including media queries) after Bootstrap's styles have been declared. In general, you'll first call the standard Bootstrap CSS file. Next you can call a customized CSS file that you generate, which contains any overrides to the base CSS along with any media queries needed.

You can also minify your CSS files, but make sure to have the base CSS styles appear first in the minified version.

Comment: Thanks very much, i thougth it was duable.